# Why is the fine stucture not included in the energy correction for problems with external magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen

In problems regarding the effect of an external magnetic field on a hydrogenlike atom, it is assumed that the total energy splitting of the $1s$ level is due to the hyperfine structure and the Zeeman effect only.

Why is the fine structure correction not included?

I understand that at the level $1s$, $l=0$ and the orbit-spin correction vanishes. But this doesn't explain the seeming irrelevance of the whole fine structure correction, which is:

$$\Delta E_{FS}=\frac {\frac 1 2 m_e c^2 \alpha ^4} {n^4} \left(\frac 3 4 -\frac n {j+\frac 1 2}\right) $$

For this case, $n=1$ and $l=0$, so $j=\frac 1 2$. Plugging these in $\Delta E _{FS}$ doesn't give zero.

Comment: The fine structure does not introduce an energy splitting of the two 1s states.  Hyperfine and Zeeman, on the other hand, do introduce a splitting.  There seems to be a second, implicit question, about why fine structure effects do not vanish for the 1s states.  That has to do with the Darwin term.